# using the Mono.TextEditor assembly to make my own text editor

Tags: mono, monodevelop, text-editor

I am trying to make my own text editor using the Mono.Texteditor.dll from MonoDeveloper v:3.0.3.2 in ubuntu 12.04.  I have boiled my code down to the simplest example and i cannot seem to get this to work.  I keep getting this error.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
'Mono.TextEditor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of 
its dependencies. File name: 'Mono.TextEditor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null' at CVXmlEditor.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
in <filename unknown>:0
```

I know it's installed and it's there I added is as a reference to my project.

My code is simple as Follows:

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using Mono.TextEditor;

public partial class MainWindow: Gtk.Window
{
 public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
 {
    Build ();

    TextEditor te = new TextEditor();
 }

 protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
 {
    Application.Quit ();
    a.RetVal = true;
 }
}
```

When is gets to the line where the text editor is constructed, it throws even though it compiles ok.  Any Ideas?

Here is the output from the debug level log.

```
Mono: The following assembly referenced from /home/bryan/Work/CVXmlEditor/TestMonoEditor/TestMonoEditor/bin/Debug/TestMonoEditor.exe could not be loaded:
 Assembly:   Mono.TextEditor    (assemblyref_index=2)
 Version:    1.0.0.0
 Public Key: (none)
The assembly was not found in the Global Assembly Cache, a path listed in the MONO_PATH environment variable, or in the location of the executing assembly (/home/bryan/Work/CVXmlEditor/TestMonoEditor/TestMonoEditor/bin/Debug/).

Mono: Failed to load assembly TestMonoEditor[0xf55400]

Mono: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.TextEditor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
The application was terminated by a signal: SIGHUP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use MonoDevelop 3.x code, as MonoDevelop 4.0 has just been released and it brings some API breaking changes. So I recommend you to use monodevelop master branch just in case.

Once you've done that, if you still hit that exception, I'm wondering if you are putting the Mono.TextEditor dll in the same folder as your executable? If yes, then try to adjust some environment variables explained here (http://www.mono-project.com/Logging_Runtime_Events) to try to know how the loader is failing to find your assembly.

Also, what version of mono is this?

Comment: mono version 2.10.8.1-5 from badgerports.  Also if i move the construction of the TextEditor object to be a global outside of the constructor, I immediately get a TypeLoadException kind of like its compiled for a different architecture.  my project is set to be .net4.0 and im on a 64 bit machine compiling x86 in settings... this should work, shouldnt it?

Comment: mono has some bugs around throwing TypeLoadException instead of FileNotFoundExceptions (like https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10354 ) so be sure to use the logging environment variables that I linked, so find the root cause

Comment: also the arch shouldn't matter, as it should all be managed code; what may matter is the profile (4.0 vs 3.5 vs 2.0)

Comment: I will enable the logging and let you know whats up by tomorrow.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The log output is above.  looks as if root owns the .dll and i need to put it into the GAC or take ownership of a copy and put it into my project.  right?

Comment: ok so i tried to copy the mono.texteditor.dll to my directory and now the mono-develop compiler crashes with this error.  It actually wont build the project anymore because of this:  Invalid type Mono.TextEditor.DocumentLine for instance field Mono.TextEditor.TextEditor:longestLine
Not a valid token for the constant table: 0x00000000
* Assertion at class.c:6469, condition `cindex' not met

Comment: that is definitely a Mono bug, I recommend you to upgrade to mono 3.0.x

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I will mark it as answered then and see what i can do about upgrading to mono 3.0